# how to get geocode of an address in javascript using webpack?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the coordinates of an address in javascript. while assingning Geocoder to a variable as:

`var geocode = new google.maps.Geocoder();`

It is throwing: `google is not defined`.

Comment: check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) and [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) , then link your geocode api in your html, it wont throw any error.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [geocoding web Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?hl=en). And make shure you added this script

`<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>`

Here 'initmap' is function, where you create geocoding object.

Comment: Thank you, but i shouldn't use script tag in my application.

Comment: google object is defined in that script. If you can't add it, you cat send web requests as showed in the link